# Error: StaticInjectorError HttpClient in shared component

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need help with this error below.

I have created a shared component using Ionic 4. I created a module inside this shared component and this module works fine with the providers mentioned below (AppVersion, Geolocation, BarcodeScanner, UniqueDeviceID, etc.) when I call my application.

My problem is:

I have put many declarations of plugins in this shared component inside this module (shared.module.ts)

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule,
IonicModule,
FormsModule//,
//HttpClientModule
],
declarations: [
LoginPage,
TrocasenhaPage,
MenulateralPage,
HomologacaoComponent
],
providers: [
AppVersion,
Geolocation,
BarcodeScanner,
UniqueDeviceID
. . .
```

When I call this application after to use HttpClient inside providers declaration, it’s showing this error:

> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UsuarioService -> HttpClient]

If I put HttpClient to try adjust the error inside providers declaration, my application shows this error:

> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]

After that, I try to put HttpClientModule inside “imports” declaration. Then, my application shows this error:

> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpHandler -> Injector]

Answer (score 0):

HttpClientModule belongs to app wide scope, it should not be in a SharedModule.

Move it to you app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and add to the imports array:

```
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
    ....
]
```

Then in a provider you import httpClient and inject it via constructor:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
....

constructor(
    public http: HttpClient
) {
}
```